# Twitter update_with_media Via Scribe OAuth On Android

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, scribe

I'm currently using Scribe to both authenticate and post non-media messages to Twitter successfully.  This was very easy, my first test message posted with no issues.  However, I can't seem to post photos at all.  I have reviewed Twitter's instructions for posting with media, both [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media) and [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059).

All of the Scribe/Twitter examples at Github are for non-media posts.  It would be great if someone could provide a solid example of how to post photos to Twitter via Scribe!

I'm have two issues in particular:

1) My posts will not pass authorization.  I've tried mimicking the examples I posted above, but nothing seems to work.

2) When converting the image from byte[] to a string, I only seem to get 4113 characters before it stops.  From my understanding, this is well under the number of characters a String can hold.

Here is how I'm extracting the photo:

```
// GET PHOTO FILE AND FILE LENGTH
// INSTANTIATE UPLOAD VARIABLE WITH FILE LENGTH

    File file      = new File(photo); // ("photo" is a string path to the photo file)
    int fileLength = (int) file.length();

    uploadFile = new byte[fileLength];

// CREATE BUFFER INPUT STREAM OF FILE

    BufferedInputStream inputStream;

    try {inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));}
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        inputStream = null;
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Buffer input stream error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

// READ DATA FROM FILE INTO UPLOAD VARIABLE
// CLOSE INPUT STREAM

    try {inputStream.read(uploadFile);}
    catch (IOException e) {Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Read input stream to upload variable error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

    try {inputStream.close();}
    catch (IOException e) {Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), "Close input stream error!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a LOT of research and piece milling code from various places I finally figured out what I was doing wrong.  Here is an example of how to post photos to Twitter via Scribe OAuth:

NOTE: This assumes a few things...

1) You have already saved the photo and have the file path

2) You have already authenticated the user at some point and have a valid access Token

3) You MUST add apache-mime4j-0.6.jar & httpmime-4.0.1.jar to you libs folder and include them in your build path!!!

I really hope this helps someone!  It's very easy to implement, but took a few days of troubleshooting to get it working correctly!

```
// BUILD OAUTH SERVICE

    OAuthService oAuth = new ServiceBuilder()
        .provider(TwitterApi.class)
        .apiKey(YOUR_TWITTER_API_KEY)        // REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN!!!
        .apiSecret(YOUR_TWITTER_API_SECRET)  // REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN!!!
        .callback(YOUR_CALLBACK)             // REPLACE WITH YOUR OWN!!!
        .build();

// BUILD OAUTH REQUEST & SIGN IT RIGHT AWAY (OTHERWISE MULTIPART FORM MAY PREVENT SIGNING)

    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json");
    oAuth.signRequest(USER_ACCESS_TOKEN, request);  // ENTER USER'S ACCESS TOKEN

// ADD MULTIPART FORM

    try
    {
        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

        entity.addPart("status", new StringBody(message));       // THIS IS THE TWITTER MESSAGE
        entity.addPart("media", new FileBody(new File(photo)));  // THIS IS THE PHOTO TO UPLOAD

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        entity.writeTo(out);

        request.addPayload(out.toByteArray());
        request.addHeader(entity.getContentType().getName(), entity.getContentType().getValue());
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

// SEND REQUEST

    try {response = new JSONObject (request.send().getBody());}
    catch (JSONException e) {Log.e("YOUR_APP_TAG", "JSONException Thrown: " + e.getMessage());}
```

Comment: OAuthService ,ServiceBuilder,TwitterApi.class, OAuthRequest.             I am unable to find these,I am using twitter4j 2.2.5

Comment: USER_ACCESS_TOKEN,  what is this? what I need to enter in this?

Comment: 02-28 14:48:53.138: E/AndroidRuntime(5994): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 14:48:53.138: E/AndroidRuntime(5994): org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Problems while creating connection.    I am getting this exception when I used this code

Comment: @user1891910 - Sorry for the late reply!  For some reason I'm not receiving notifications.  This code is for use with Scribe (https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java), not Twitter4J!!!

Comment: @Jabari Is there a way to do that without httpmime & mime4j but with jersey-multipart? Couldn't figure it out myself.

Comment: @Nils - Not that I've found...to be honest, after as many hours it took me to get this working reliably I didn't attempt any alterations afterwards.